# Spring send formdata with files and value of input ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I need to send by post a file array that grows dynamically. Apart from that, I need to send the value of two input together. The code as it works, but if I add more through data.append ("input1", input1); I do not receive when making the ajax request.
Is there any way to do it? Because I'm not seeing how to do it. I am using spring 1.5.7 and thymeleaf.

```
@PostMapping("/upload/multi")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> multiUploadFileModel(@RequestBody MultipartFile[] file) {


        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

//My JS works without append other data.

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    var data = new FormData();

    var input1 = $('#input1').val();
    var input2 = $('#input2').val();

    $.each(files,function(i,file){
        data.append('file', file);
    })
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },  
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data', 
        url: "/upload/multi",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            if(xhr.status==404) {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use @RequestParam instead of @RequestBody like this..

```
@PostMapping("/upload/multi")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> multiUploadFileModel(@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile[] file, @RequestParam("input1") String input1, @RequestParam("input2") String input2) {


        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Successfully uploaded!", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Change the types of input1 and input2 to correct types if they are not strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was the solution I was looking for. I leave the code if in the doubts it serves another person.

//JS
var data = new FormData();
 var input1 = $('#dni').val();
 var input2 = $('#descripcioncalif').val();
 $.each(files, function(i, file) {
  data.append('file', file);
 }); 
 data.append("input1", input1);
 data.append("input2", input2);
 $.ajax({
  data : data..............

//Spring
@RequestParam(name = "input1") String input1,
   @RequestParam(name = "input2") String input2, @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile[] file)